# Check if Cell value exists in Column, and then get the value of the NEXT Cell

Tags: excel

After checking if a cell value exists in a column, I need to **get the value of the cell next to the matching cell**. For instance, I check if the value in `cell A1` exists in `column B`, and assuming it matches `B5`, then I want the value in `cell C5`.

To solve the first half of the problem, I did this...

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B, 0)), "No Match", "Match")
```

...and it worked. Then, thanks to an [earlier answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12642375/979621), I was also able to obtain the row number of the matching cell:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B, 0)), "No Match", "Match on Row " & MATCH(A1,B:B, 0))
```

So naturally, to get the value of the next cell, I tried...

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B, 0)), "No Match", C&MATCH(A1,B:B, 0))
```

...and it doesn't work.

What am I missing? How do I append the column number to the row number returned to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After [t.thielemans' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12915478/979621), I worked that just

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, B:C, 2, FALSE)
```

works fine and does what I wanted, except that it returns `#N/A` for non-matches; so it is suitable for the case where it is known that the value definitely exists in the look-up column.

**Edit** (based on t.thielemans' comment): 
To avoid `#N/A` for non-matches, do:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, B:C, 2, FALSE), "No Match")
```

Comment: Use this instead `IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, B:C, 2, FALSE),0)`. I also added this to my answer. 0 being whatever value you want :) (use this in the code will lead to No Match if no match is found ;)

Answer (score 102):

Use a different function, like VLOOKUP:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B, 0)), "No Match", VLOOKUP(A1,B:C,2,FALSE))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works too! And I think it'd be better to use `VLOOKUP(A1, B:C, 2, FALSE)` instead of using a fixed range (so as to accommodate a growing look-up array)?

Comment: Yeah, just used this fixed range as a test. Edited it in my answer.

Comment: You don't need `IFERROR` here. It works fine without it, because the VLOOKUP is only executed if there is a match.

Comment: Oops! I seem to have been testing in the wrong column :P Indeed without IFERROR it works perfectly too :P

Comment: This is older than old, but I just wanted to say that I've been using this for years and it really bugs me that you were never given best answer. I love that it makes the table scalable for comparing multiple columns.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how can I apply this formula in excel? I mean in which cell which and how.

Comment: You put it in any cell you like, depends on your layout

Comment: The parameter in the VLOOKUP function where it says 2, how can I copy cell content 4 cells away? Since 2 seems to work if you'll copy the next cell. I tried looking for another solution, but can't find one and putting other number aside from 2 doesn't work. Hope you could help.

Answer (score 8):

How about this?

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B, 0)), "No Match", INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(A1,B:B, 0), 3)))
```

The "3" at the end means for column C.

Comment: Fantastic! I just tried exactly that (based on [Excel: get content of a cell given the row and column numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4813888/979621)), and was about to answer my own question, but you beat me to it! Thanks, it works great!