# Copy multiple data columns with the same key from another sheet excel

Tags: excel

I want to copy multiple columns with the same key from one Excel sheet to another.

Example:

**Sheet 1**:

```
123 | a | aa  
123 | b | bb  
123 | c | cc  
234 | d | dd  
234 | e | ee  
55  | f | ff  
123 | g | gg
```

**Sheet 2**:

One cell where I put my key; in this case `123`; and I want to have every column from sheet 1 shown on sheet 2, with key `123`.
So it has to look like this on sheet 2:

```
Key:123

automaticly shown:  
123 | a | aa  
123 | b | bb  
123 | c | cc  
123 | g | gg
```

I guess it is one of the easier things to do, but I am pretty new to Excel.
I do not want to use VBA code. I just want to use normal functions which you put in a cell, like `IF` etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel: Check if Cell value exists in Column, and then get the value of the NEXT Cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915215/excel-check-if-cell-value-exists-in-column-and-then-get-the-value-of-the-next)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have data in *Sheet1* like:

[image]

and we want to retrieve records with the value **123** in column **A**.  We can use:

- AutoFilter to display only the **123** rows and then use Copy/Paste
- Use a VBA macro to do the Copy/Paste
- Use formulas to retrieve the rows

To implement the third method we need to:

1. first get the required row number(s)
2. then get the row's contents using *INDEX()*

In *Sheet2* cell **A1** enter the *array formula*:

```
=SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$22=123,ROW($A$1:$A$22),9E+99),ROW())
```

and copy this cell downwards.

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Then in *Sheet2* cell **B1** enter the normal formula:

```
=IF($A1>22,"",INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,$A1))
```

Finally copy **B1** and paste to the rectangular area from **B1** through **D22**

*Sheet2* displays:

[image]

*(ignore the junk appearing at the bottom of column **A**)*

Answer (score 0):

Insert->PivotTable. Put all three headers into row labels. Set filter on 1st col to be equal to 123.