# EXCEL: Vlookup and Match Function - to get the cell value next to it

Tags: excel, match, cell, vlookup

I have 2 sheets. One is for the **child table** and the other is for the **master table**. I need to get the master_id from the master table which is in the master table sheet.

As you can see below, with the formula i get from this [Excel: Check if Cell value exists in Column, and then get the value of the NEXT Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915215/excel-check-if-cell-value-exists-in-column-and-then-get-the-value-of-the-next), it didn't work for me.

Thank you.

**Child Table**

```
    A              B                C
child_id      reference_no      master_id
1             2017001           =IF(MATCH(B2,master.B2:B15,1), "NO MATCH", VLOOKUP(B2,master.A2:B15,2,0))
2             2017002           NO MATCH
```

**Master Table**

```
    A             B
master_id     reference_no
a1            2017002
a2            2017003
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INDEX` returns the particular row in a table.

`MATCH` returns the position of a value in a table.

You want to use them together:

[image: IndexMatch]

Answer (score 1):

The problem with what you are trying to do is that `VLOOKUP` searches for a key in the first column, and then gives the option of returning either the value in that column or the column immediately to the right.  But your `Master` table has it backwards, with the key in column `B` and the value you want in column `A`.

I might recommend that your refactor your master spreadsheet as follows:

**Master Table**

```
A             B
reference_no  master_id
2017002       a1
2017003       a2
```

Then you can enter the following formula into column `C` of your child spreadsheet:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,master.A2:B10,2,FALSE),"Not found")
```

If you cannot/don't want to change your master spreadsheet, there are workarounds, but the formulas are more complex than what I have above, q.v. here:

https://superuser.com/questions/645039/excel-vlookup-by-second-column-using-table-name-as-range