# Type mismatch , compare excel cell value to array value *FIXED*

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript, match, type-mismatch

Current problem:

Target is to copy data from a source .csv file to a target excel sheet, based on matching a value from each row of the .csv to values in an excel sheet column, and then making the copy based on that to the correct cells in the excel sheet.

I'm gathering values to an array from a .csv file in a loop, comparing one of the values in the array to values in the target excel sheet column A, if a match happens, all the values in the array are to be copied to the corresponding row in the excel sheet.

I'm now getting a "Type mismatch" error when trying to compare the excel sheet's cell values to the array value.

Here are the relevant bits of the code:

```
sfile="\\DFSpath\file1.csv"
smaster="\\DFSpath\file2.xlsx"

set xlapp = createobject("excel.application")

set wbtarget = xlapp.workbooks.open(smaster)

set tgtworksheet = wbtarget.worksheets("sheet1")

set usedRowsXP = tgtworksheet.UsedRange.Rows

dim fs,objTextFile
set fs=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim arrStr
set objTextFile = fs.OpenTextFile(sfile)

Do while NOT objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
  arrStr = split(objTextFile.ReadLine,",")

    for each oRow in usedRowsXP   

    Introw = oRow
    If tgtworksheet.cells(Introw,1).value = arrStr(2) Then
    tgtworksheet.cells(Introw,4).value = arrStr(0)
    tgtworksheet.cells(Introw,5).value = arrStr(1)
    tgtworksheet.cells(Introw,6).value = arrStr(2)

    End If
    next
Loop
```

Fixed by modifying the code as follows:

```
dim fs,objTextFile
    set fs=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    dim arrStr
    set objTextFile = fs.OpenTextFile(sfile)

'##Replace quotation marks with nothing in .csv##

strText = objtextFile.ReadAll
objTextFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, """", "")

Set objtextFile = fs.OpenTextFile(sfile, 2)
objtextFile.Write strNewText
objtextFile.Close

set objTextFile = fs.OpenTextFile(sfile, 1)

'##Gather array out of line in .csv + compare user's name to name in excel sheet, if matches, copy data, repeat for each line##


Do while NOT objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
arrStr = split(objTextFile.ReadLine,",")     

for each oRow in usedRowsXP   

Introw = oRow.row
If Cstr(tgtworksheet.cells(Introw,1).value) = arrStr(2) Then
tgtworksheet.cells(Introw,4).value = arrStr(0)
tgtworksheet.cells(Introw,5).value = arrStr(1)
tgtworksheet.cells(Introw,6).value = arrStr(2)

End If
next

Loop
```

Comment: What is the exact error and at what line? If you debug have you checked the values and types of the variables in that line? For example if your error is on the line tgtworksheet.cells(Introw,1).value = arrStr(2) then what type is arrStr(2) and what type is tgtworksheet.cells(Introw,1).value?? If you know the values are going to be numbers then declare your variables as such, if you kow you need strings then declare as strings.

Comment: It fails on the line: If tgtworksheet.cells(Introw,1).value = arrStr(2) Then , The error is "Type mismatch" code: 800A000D , runtime error. I tried already with the cell values by value.ToString , but no dice, same error. The contents of the 2 locations to compare are formatted similar: SURNAME Firstname . ArrStr values can be echoed out but the excel cell values can't be, produces same type mismatch error.

Comment: I think your issue is Introw - I'll bet it is a row object and not an integer. If you know the first row number then declare Introw as that integer and replace "Introw = oRow" with "Introw = Introw + 1"

Comment: Or else does the row object have cell children? Maybe you can replace tgtworksheet.cells(Introw,1).value with oRow.cells(1, 1).value or oRow.columns(1).value or something like that?

Comment: Worked with oRow.row , now my only concern is how to exclude the brackets from the csv array value , so that the value can be matched with the excel sheet value

Comment: Excuse my english, I was referring to the quotation marks, not brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is in this row:

```
for each oRow in usedRowsXP  
Introw = oRow
```

I'm not really good at VBA, but I think that usedRowsXP is a Range, and each row of it will also be a range. Therefore Introw will be a range. Try using the Row property of oRow, it will return its row number:

```
for each oRow in usedRowsXP  
Introw = oRow.Row
```

After that Introw should work fine in the Cells(Introw, 1) etc. expression.

Comment: oRow.row works, Now the problem is only that array value is "SURNAME firstname" and cell value SURNAME Firstname , so the cell value is without brackets. I already tried with Cstr(...), but the value stays in the same format

Comment: I'll take this back, both values are strings, the brackets come from the csv sheet itself

Comment: now my only concern is how to exclude the brackets from the csv array value , so that the value can be matched with the excel sheet value

Comment: The syntax would be something like this: `Replace(arrStr(2), """", "")` This will replace the quote marks to empty string. Write this in the row where you match the two values, and therefore it will match the unquoted name.

Comment: I was hoping to get in the split(objTextFile.ReadLine,",") , but it doesn't accept quotation marks inside quotation marks. This way the quotation marks would not be copied in any of the array values

Comment: Try `Split(Replace(objTextFile.ReadLine, """", ""),",")`. First the quotes will be deleted, and the remaining text will be split at every comma. In this case """" means a string with this content: ". Two double quotes is the escape character for a single quote string.